# Vuetify card expand overlap error in Masonry.js

Tags: vuetify.js, masonry

I have created a card in which I added a expand button at the bottom. It works perfectly fine in normal mode but when I integrate Masonry.js then the card is working fine and when I expand the bottom of the card it overlaps with the bottom element

image 1

[image: In normal mode it is working fine]

image 2

[image: Overlap when I expand the card]

```
<v-row class="masonry">
  <v-col
    class="pa-3"
    cols="12"
    md="4"
    sm="6"
    v-for="program in allPrograms"
    :key="program._id"
  >
    <single-card :content="program"></single-card> </v-col
></v-row>

<script>
  mounted: function () {
    var msnry = new Masonry( '.masonry', {
    itemSelector: "[class*='col-']",
  });
 </script>
```

Card expansion code

```
  <v-card-actions>
    <v-btn color="orange" text @click="openLink(content.timeline)">
      Timeline
    </v-btn>

    <v-spacer></v-spacer>

    <v-btn icon @click="show = !show">
      <v-icon>{{ show ? "mdi-chevron-up" : "mdi-chevron-down" }}</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </v-card-actions>

  <v-expand-transition>
    <div v-show="show">
      <v-divider></v-divider>

      <v-card-text class="text-justify">
        {{ content.description }}
      </v-card-text>
    </div>
  </v-expand-transition>
```

Answer (score 0):

after doing a lot of research I found a way to solve it for this I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-masonry  instead of masonry.js

so after every click, we need to redraw our masonry for this we have to use a function `this.$redrawVueMasonry('containerId')`

for more detail head over to https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-masonry